# If condition inside <td> HTML

Tags: html, bash, sqlite, html-table, cgi

I am making a cgi script that reads the content of a sql database and displays them inside a table. I want to put a condition for column that if the text inside it the date today i want to have a green background color for the cell.
The line i want to ad the condition is :

```
echo '<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; 
charset=UTF-8">'
echo '<style>body {font-family: courier;}</style></head>'
echo "<body>"
echo "<table border="1">"
echo "<tr><th>lfd.</th><th>ID</th><th>Name/Ort</th><th class="y_n"}>Last Seen</th></tr>"
for line in $(sqlite3 onlinestatus.sqlite "SELECT playerid,name,lastseen,lfd FROM devices WHERE playerid = "1234"
do 
echo "<tr>"
echo "<td align="right">$(echo ${line}|cut -d "|" -f 4)</td>"
echo "<td align="right">$(echo ${line}|cut -d "|" -f 1)</td>"
echo "<td>$(echo ${line}|cut -d "|" -f 2)</td>"
echo "<td>$(echo ${line}|cut -d "|" -f 3)</td>"
echo "</tr>"
done 
echo "</table>"
```

I want to add to this line the condition so if the ${line} is todays date the background color for the cell is green or any other color

```
echo "<td align="right">$(echo ${line}|cut -d "|" -f 1)</td>"
```

Comment: So whats the problem?

Comment: @123 how can i add if condition into the <td> so if the text inside the cell is todays date it gives a green background color?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the innermost double quotes are not interpreted as inner double quotes but closing the string as the syntax coloring shows well.

To use double quotes inside double quoted string it can be escaped

```
echo "<td align=\"right\">$(echo ${line}|cut -d \"|\" -f 1)</td>"
```

Or you can use single quotes

```
echo '<td align="right">'"$(echo ${line}|cut -d '|' -f 1)"'</td>'
```

Also cut is useless, the following variable expansion does the same

```
echo '<td align="right">'"${line%%|*}"'</td>'
```

Except when inner quotes are between command substitution $(), in that case they can be nested.